# defaultSortDirection config not present in store of EXT-JS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect, extjs5

I have upgraded my project from Ext-js 4.2 to Ext-js5.
In Ext-js 5 there is no config such as **defaultSortDirection** present which was there in Ext-js 4.2 .

Can anyone help me out if there is some alternative present for this.

Thanks & Regards
 Sumanth K.P

Answer (score 0):

Use the sorters property, see [store documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store).

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     sorters: [{
         property: 'age',
         direction: 'DESC'
     }, {
         property: 'firstName',
         direction: 'ASC'
     }],

     filters: [{
         property: 'firstName',
         value: /Ed/
     }]
 });
```

There is a related config sortOnLoad which tells the store to apply these sorter configs on load, but you shouldn't need to worry about this as it defaults to true.

Comment: Hi ,  
Thanks for reply.  
I want to send a parameter to service such as **dir = 'ÁSC' OR dir = 'DESC'**
In previous version because of **defaultSortDirection** config this used to happen automatically.
But, now even if i add it in sorter it wont be sent in request parameter.